# CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer bits/component iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the problem with creating context..

I have seen lots of answer but none of this working for me.

I have the following code.

```
CGSize pixelSize = src_img.size;
pixelSize.width = src_img.scale* src_img.size.width;
pixelSize.height = src_img.scale*src_img.size.height;

size_t d_bytesPerRow = pixelSize.width * 4;
unsigned char *imgData = (unsigned char*)malloc(pixelSize.height * d_bytesPerRow);
CGImageRef imageRef = src_img.CGImage;

CGContextRef context =  CGBitmapContextCreate(imgData,
                                              (size_t)pixelSize.width, (size_t)pixelSize.height, 8, d_bytesPerRow,
                                              CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef), kCGImageAlphaNone);
```

In console shows me the error

> CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer
>   bits/component; 24 bits/pixel; 3-component color space;
>   kCGImageAlphaNone; 1754 bytes/row.

I don't know what to do. Please help

Answer (score 12):

You are not specifying one of the [supported pixel formats](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB). The image's colorspace is apparently an RGB color space. You're specifying `kCGImageAlphaNone`. Together, that means 3 components per pixel and no padding. Combined with the 8 bits per component that you specified gives 24 bits per pixel.

None of the supported pixel formats allow for 24 bits per pixel. That's another way of saying that none of them supports RGB with `kCGImageAlphaNone`. If you don't have or want alpha, you need to use either `kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst` or `kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast`, which means a byte of padding in each pixel bumping it up to 32 bits per pixel.

Also, you're almost always better off specifying `NULL` for the `data` parameter and 0 for the `bytesPerRow` parameter. The former makes memory management much easier. The latter is not only easier, but allows the system to optimize the buffer's alignment.

Answer (score 2):

Since the error messages says “1754 bytes/row”, and you're computing the bytes/row as `4 * src_img.size.width`, I can solve for `src_img.size.width = 1754 / 4 = 438.5`.  You can't have half a pixel in your bitmap.

I suspect you have a `UIImage` with a `scale` of 2.  A `UIImage`s dimensions are measured in points, but a `CGBitmapContext`'s dimensions are measured in pixels.  To convert the `UIImage`'s dimensions to pixels, you need to multiply by its `scale`.

```
CGSize pixelSize = src_img.size;
pixelSize.width *= src_img.scale;
pixelSize.height *= src_image.scale;

size_t d_bytesPerRow = pixelSize.width * 4;
unsigned char *imgData = (unsigned char*)malloc(pixelSize.height * d_bytesPerRow);
CGImageRef imageRef = src_img.CGImage;

CGContextRef context =  CGBitmapContextCreate(imgData,
    (size_t)pixelSize.width, (size_t)pixelSize.height, 8, d_bytesPerRow,
    CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef), kCGImageAlphaNone);
```

You will also need to take the scale into account if you plan to draw the image into the context, perhaps by using `CGContextScaleCTM`.

Comment: yes i have scaled  CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0); but the problem is that CGContextRef always come nil.. i have tried above code but not working

Comment: What is `src_image.scale`?  Did you try multiplying the sizes by `scale`?  If so, edit your question to include your modified code.

Comment: I have updated my question please check